# Lookup and replace specific values with reference in pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

If I'm trying to find specific names in a list given from my pivot table such as -

```
Row Labels              Revenues    Order #

   Panera               25          0
        Pasta           15         
        Salad           10

   Olive Garden         40          0 
        Sandwich        20
        Pasta           20

   Panda Express        30          0 
        Rice            15
        Chicken         15
```

And I want to search through my document, find Olive Garden and Panda Express and I wanted to replace the 0 in the order # column with 10 for Olive Garden and 20 for Panda Express. Currently, someone here helped me out with

```
=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A9,worksheet!K:K,1,FALSE),"")="","",0)
```

which inserts 0's for the headers and blanks for the orders in the 'Order #' column, can I add a second formula that would find the names and replace the value in that column? Or adjust the current formula?

Quick note - order # column is not from the pivot table.

To make it more clear, - I am getting data from an external source (i.e. paper invoices), as opposed to making a manual entry to adjust the 0's in the order # column, I would like to tell VBA/Excel - "hey Olive Garden's order number is 10 and Panda Express's order number changed to 20, adjust".

this is my end goal -

```
Row Labels              Revenues    Order #

   Panera               25          0
        Pasta           15         
        Salad           10

   Olive Garden         40          10 
        Sandwich        20
        Pasta           20

   Panda Express        30          20
        Rice            15
        Chicken         15
```

Comment: Where do the order numbers you want to adjust live? How is that data structured? Provide an example with worksheet name and cell addresses. Also, what does A9 in the vlookup refer to? What data is in `worksheet!K:K` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a range with the restaurant names in one column and the order numbers in the next column (say columns X and Y of the sheet called "worksheet"), you could change your formula to be

`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A9,worksheet!K:K,0),"")="","",IFERROR(VLOO‌​KUP(A9,worksheet!X:Y‌​,2,FALSE),0))`

(P.S. Changed the original `VLOOKUP` to `MATCH` based on useful feedback from teylyn.)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, that formula would be better using MATCH, not VLookup, since it's returning the value from the first column.

But back on track: what are you trying to achieve? Change the values in a pivot table?

First, a formula cannot change values in another cell. 
Second, a pivot table reports on existing data. You can't change the numbers that a pivot table reports.

You will need to re-think your approach. If you don't like the numbers the pivot table returns, you'll need to change the underlying source data.

Comment: Should've mentioned this - but the order # column is not from the pivot table and self added and filled by the if(vlookup) function - my goal is just to change specific values corresponding to a specific restaurant (in this case) - this is me trying to avoid data entry essentially, and if there's a way to do it in VBA that would be great as well. I just want to be able to find specific restaurant names and adjust their order # to a specific value, otherwise leave it as 0 if there's no need for adjustments.

Comment: Edit your question and put the details into the question. It's not clear what you want to achieve. The formula right now returns 0, but you want it to return WHAT? Find WHAT and replace with WHAT? It's not clear. Give an example. In your question. Post a comment when you've done that, to alert the people who are following your question.

Comment: Edited - at this point, I'm at a loss of what to clarify. I am merely trying to avoid manual entry - I need to adjust specific numbers in the order # column that I've manually added to the pivot table data.